# Delete Column A if Column B is blank

Tags: vb.net, excel

Can someone tell me what VB code I can use, to obtain the following macro excel result?

I want for content from column A to be deleted if column B is blank. This is how far I have come:

```
If Range ("B66")= IsEmpty Then 
Range ("A66").Select 
Selection.ClearContents 
End If
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I changed my questions.I hope it's more clear this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Main()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Long, r As Range
    For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        Set r = Range("A" & i)
        If IsEmpty(r.Offset(0, 1)) Then r.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
    Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

first you need a loop to cycle through all cells in column A

`For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1` sets up a loop that iterates from the last cell to the first one in column A

`Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` finds the last cell used in column A

`Set r = Range("A" & i)` sets r variable to be a Range object

`If IsEmpty(r.Offset(0, 1)) Then` Offset points to cell in column B on the same row, so if it the neighbouring cell of column A (which is cell(sameRow, column B) is empty then

`r.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp` delete entire row

`Application.ScreenUpdating = False/True` turn off screen updating to speed up the execution when using loops

Comment: Why delete EntireRow.. dont you mean `EntireColumn` ?

Comment: it doesn't really make sense in both English and programming logic to delete entire Column. I think the OP meant ROWS actually. Also his psuedo-code makes me think he means `row` when he says `column`

Comment: @adp we say thank you buy accepting answers that are helpful to us :)